# npm ERR! cb() never called

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I was trying to download expo cli and I got error:-

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm i -g expo-cli
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-03T14_02_14_809Z-debug.log
```

I also used **npm cache clean --force**.
But it didn't work too

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -v
7.6.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v
v14.16.0
```

Please help me......

And after doing **npm i -g npm** it worked!!!!!!

But when I tried to install or download any packages then error:

```
E:\React-native\practice>npm i react-native-elements
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-04T05_03_20_067Z-debug.log
```

So what is wrong going on?

Comment: I'm having same issue trying to create next app, did you find a solution or somethin' ?

Comment: Just keep Internet speed high and try npm cache clean --force and try again

Comment: Is there any elaboration why does this error happens? I always see solutions that never refer to the real cause of the problem and nobody know what does it even mean?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using npm version 5 or above:

Try following command:

$ sudo npm cache verify

OR

$ sudo npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 3):

I did the following steps:

1. delete node_modules
2. remove package-lock.json
3. run *npm cache clean --force*
4. run *npm install --force*

`npm install --force` was the key to success, because even after doing 1-2 steps, normal `npm install` resulted in same problem

Comment: what the hell, `npm install --force` was helpful. Confusing that years later this is still an issue. (I am using node 14.20.1, complete fresh install)

Answer (score 2):

```
Run npm install -g npm & npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, and was able to fix it by adding the flag `--legacy-peer-deps` to the installation command. For instance:

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps package-name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with checking my proxxy settings in C:\Users\username.npmrc

here are the settings for the proxy.

```
proxy=...
https-proxy=...
strict-ssl=false
registry=...
```

You can set these things through npm with the following:

```
 npm config set proxy ...
 npm config set https-proxy ...
 npm config set strict-ssl false
 npm config set registry ...
```

Maybe you have to remove proxy and https-proxy to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in all npm package that I tried to download, and solved just running this command in my Windows CMD.

> npm set strict-ssl true

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to force clean the npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```